# How to create an array in firebase database in iOS swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to create an **Array** in **Firebase** realtime database in iOS using swift

note : I want to be able to append new elements without getting array value first an add element locally then setting it to database .

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate more? Because  "Firebase has no native support for arrays." So, what exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to store messages of a conversation

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *childByAutoId()*

```
Database.database().reference().child("arrayKey").childByAutoId().setValue("Value") }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be achieved easily:

```
let ref = storageRef.child("your_child")
let array = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
ref.setValue(array)
```

Comment: I have tried this but adding o an element requires an api call to get all elements and then add the element  locally and then setting it back to database .

Comment: can you please show your code / what you achieved so far?